# Why android adb not see devices?

Tags: android

I install android sdk command line tools and run emulator

adb devices

```
List of devices attached
emulator-5558   device
```

Now i try install apk file to device
adb -d install app-release-unsigned.apk

```
adb: no devices found
```

where is the mistake?

I try reinstall sdk
and try reinstall adb

Comment: `adb devices` should show physical devices and emulators. `adb -d` means only physical device which `adb` says does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

**Update ADB Driver**

An outdated ADB interface driver can result in the error - device not found or ADB no devices/emulators found in Windows 11/10. To help you out, it is necessary to install a new version for that driver.

===========================================================================

For a physical device to make sure ADB works perfectly, you should enable USB debugging on your Android device. Or else, the ADB error device not found appears.

Step 1: On your Android phone, go to **Settings > About.**

Step 2: Tap on **Build number** seven times to activate **Developer options.**

Step 3: Enable **USB debugging**.